# Appropriate test for comparing categories in two groups?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, stata

I have a subset of a data as below: I would like to compare two groups (1/0) for 6 categories for using a medication Every week they could choose more than one option for each question. The number of responses for each response option during the full study period and test differences between group (1) and group (0). The data below is created in the way that column A means, counting the number of A, and same for other columns. Chi-square test is correct? If chi-square test is not correct, then which test is appropriate and how to do it in R or STATA?

```
structure(list(A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6), B = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1), D = c(0, 7, 1, 0, 0, 8, 6, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0), E = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0), F = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the question that the analysis should answer?

Comment: The data structure is not clear to me. Does everyone in your data take medications type A-G? Or is there a column missing for that? What does 8 mean if there are only 7 options? Are the 7 options the same for each medication type? Or is 6 for A different than a 6 for G?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to compare if there are any differences in how frequently each reason is given across the two groups is to use a regression.

Below, I fit a linear model for the expected number that each reason was given by each group using Stata. To do this, it helps to reshape the data into the "long" panel format from wide. The standard errors are clustered to reflect that you have 7 reasons for each of the 12 people. I then plot the predictions. I also calculate the difference between the predictions and do a hypothesis test that two of the largest differences are zero to probe if the differences are statistically distinguishable from noise.

```
clear
input id A B C D E F G group
1  0 0 0 0 0 1 0     0
2  0 0 0 7 0 0 0     0
3  0 0 0 1 0 0 0     1
4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0     1
5  0 0 0 0 0 1 0     1
6  0 0 0 8 0 0 0     0
7  1 2 0 6 0 3 0     1
8  0 0 0 6 4 0 0     0
9  0 0 0 2 0 0 0     1
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     0
11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     1
12 6 2 1 0 0 0 0     1
end
cls
rename A-G count=
reshape long count, i(id group) j(reason) string
capture ssc install sencode
sencode reason, replace label(reason)
order id group reason count
compress
xtset id reason
regress count i.reason##i.group, vce(cluster id)
margins reason#group
marginsplot, name(yhats, replace) ylab(#8) title("Expected Number That Each Reason Given by Group") nodraw xtitle("")
margins reason, dydx(group) post // coefl
marginsplot, name(effects, replace) yline(0) plotopt(lcolor(tt_green) mcolor(tt_green)) ciopt(lcolor(tt_green)) ylab(#8) ///
title("Group 1 vs Group 0 Difference in Expected Times Given") nodraw
graph combine yhats effects, cols(1) xcommon ycommon
// hypothesis test that A and D gaps are jointly zero vs not 
test (_b[1.group:1.reason] = 0) (_b[1.group:4.reason] = 0)
// hypothesis test that reasons A and D gaps are the same vs different
test _b[1.group:1.reason] = _b[1.group:4.reason]
```

The graphs look like this:
[image]

It looks like reason D is frequently given, especially by group 0. The next largest difference is reason A, though that favors group 1. Both CIs overlap with zero (and you get p-values for each separate hypothesis from `margins`).

You can test the hypothesis that Reason A and Reason D differences are both zero. The results look like this:

```
. test (_b[1.group:1.reason] = 0) (_b[1.group:4.reason] = 0)

 ( 1)  [1.group]1bn.reason = 0
 ( 2)  [1.group]4.reason = 0

       F(  2,    11) =    1.64
            Prob > F =    0.2375
```

The p-value is 0.24, so you cannot reject the null that the two differences aren't zero.

You can also test that the gaps are merely equal:

```
. test _b[1.group:1.reason] = _b[1.group:4.reason]

 ( 1)  [1.group]1bn.reason - [1.group]4.reason = 0

       F(  1,    11) =    3.14
            Prob > F =    0.1039
```

This gives you a lower p-value of 0.10, but you cannot reject this null either. Lots of other comparisons are possible.

Comment: @user358238 Did this clear things up?